# Angular JS SPA: How to Angular Controller SPA to call Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a Node.js Application with Angular.js and Express.js.

What I'm doing is to add customer names with address to list (random) with this code.

```
var mylist = new generic.list();
mylist.add({name:"Rohan",add:"Sec 49, Noida"});
mylist.add({name:"Sam",add:"Sec 63, Noida"});
mylist.add({name:"Jack",add:"Sec 15, Noida"});
```

Now I want to add following features in it

```
Angular Controller - customerController to call an angular service
Angular Service - dataService - to call node js API (implemented earlier) using $http.
Angular View – customers.html - to display list of customers. Display the count of customers at the bottom of the SPA page.
```

I'm stuck, Kindly help. How to move from this step.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: I've given you a working example below.  Let  me know if you have any questions.  Please mark as accepted if it works for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a working Plnkr example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YevOesJ7Jhy4wpMWiQvE?p=preview, or see the code below.

Here's your controller

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('CustomerController', CustomerController);
  CustomerController.$inject = ["dataService"];

  function CustomerController( dataService) {
    var vm = this;

    activate();

    function activate() {
      dataService.GetData()
        .then(function(results) {
        vm.data = results;
        },
      function(error) {})
        .finally(function() {
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

Here's your data service:  You'll need to change the HTTP call to access the node.js API instead of list.json.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
   angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('dataService', dataService);

   dataService.$inject = ['$q', '$timeout', '$http'];

   function dataService($q, $timeout, $http) {
     var data = [];
     console.log("Number of table entries is: " + data.length);
     var promise = $http.get('list.json');
     promise.then(function(response) {
     data = response.data;
     console.log("Number of table entries is now: " + data.length);
   });

   return {
     GetData: getData
   };

   function getData() {
     return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        $timeout(function() {
          resolve(data);
        }, 3000);
     });
   }
 }
})();
```

Here's your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="controller.js"></script>
  <script src="data.service.js"></script>
  <script src="list.json"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="CustomerController as vm">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="record in vm.data">
          <td>{{record.name}}</td>
          <td>{{record.add}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```